# Path Replacement Pattern - Views Module

Tags: views, path-aliases

I am using [PathAuto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to redirect user urls to the following pattern. `users/[user:name]`.

I have created a page using the views module which needs to show up as a tab on the user naviagation menu. Currently the PATH property for the page is set to `/user/%/seasons`.

Here is my issue.

My account is Uid=1, UserName = 'Declan'.

Pathauto renders that as '/users/declan' - which is what I want.

When I click on the 'Seasons' tab, the page is rendered, but the url is '/user/1/seasons'.

Is there any way to rewrite the PATH property in the view such that is will render '/users/declan/seasons'?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, the [Sub-pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module does the job perfectly.